# How to get pygame bar width with method?

Tags: python, pygame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smOj6.png)How I can get width of pygame bar? I mean the gray taskbar. I've tried to to following but it does not work properly.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
disp = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
disp.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
title = 'text'
pygame.display.set_caption(title)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

But the text is positioned to the left side. I I use  pygame.display.set_caption(f"{title: > 320}") it goes out of window.

Try to figure how to get width of the bar and then position text to center.

Answer (score -1):

You Can get the the bar width Beacause
Bar Width = Screen width.
and this code is how i put the text in the center

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
ScreenWidth,ScreenHight = 640, 480
disp = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenWidth, ScreenHight))
disp.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
title = 'textdd'
spaces = " "
spacecount = (round(640/7)-(len(title)))

print(spacecount)

for c in range(spacecount):
    spaces = ' '+spaces

pygame.display.set_caption(spaces+title)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have one question. Where does that 7 divider comes from?

Comment: because the font size of the title is 7 px so I want to get how many characters can be on the title bar